# Has anyone installed Oracle JDeveloper Studio 12c on M1/Apple Silicon Mac OS 13 Ventura?

Tags: macos, jdeveloper, apple-silicon

I'm following the Oracle documentation exactly when attempting to install either Jdev Studio version 12.2.1.3 or 12.2.1.4. I know it says Java jdk/jre 8 is required, so I've been sticking to that after originally failing to install with openjdk.

[Installation Instructions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/fusion-middleware/12.2.1.4/install/toc.htm)
(linked 12.2.1.4 only because both are similar and I figured this newer one has a higher chance of working)

I've tried both the generic and Linux specific installers for Jdev, renaming files as instructions state, and both installer versions still fail to open. I already have this working on an Intel Mac running macOS 12, but I need to setup new devices. So I'm wondering, is it even possible to get it working on macOS 13 Ventura? Info for troubleshooting online is sparse. Does anybody have JDev working on an Apple Silicon Mac?

Comment: And what is the actual problem you have?

Comment: Thanks for asking. The linux specific download is a bin file that wont open with error: "Unable to expand ["filename"]. It is in an unsupported format."

The generic installer which should work across any device with Java installed is a jar file or multiple jar files in the most recent installers case. They will not open when java command is used on them in terminal and produce message: unable to access jarfile (this is a new development I'm currently looking into as they used to say zsh permission denied).

Comment: If I open the jar normally, an error appears telling me: " Java application launch failed. Check console for possible error message related to [jar filename]." But it appears to me there are no related errors in the console.

So far, I've failed to find a working solution to any of these issue online.
And Sorry. First time using stack overflow, and I accidentally submitted that vague first problem which it didn't let me edit. Edit: vague first problem deleted

Comment: Which java version do you use to run the jar?

Comment: Java 8u351

However, in other news, I was able to get the jar to produce a log file. Problem is it says it's located in Mac hidden folders at /private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/T/OraInstall2023-03-08_11-18-53AM/launcher2023-03-08_11-18-53AM.log. 

I'm system admin, but once I try to gain access, it says "Folder 'T' can't be opened because you don't have permission to see its contents." I can't change the folder permissions either because it also says I don't have permission. If only there were a way to redirect the log file to a folder I can access.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think the relative location of the log may be hardcoded in the source code of the jar installer.

Comment: Welp, I may not have had access to that folder, but a workaround was to copy the 6 GB folder to desktop. Then I was able to view the logs. All I found was "The current user is root or has superuser privilege. The Oracle Universal Installer cannot continue."

I took a wild guess and removed sudo from my terminal command when I ran java. That seemed to solve it for now, and I actually got an installation window. Just had to manually override a subsequent prompt that failed to check if CPU speed was above 300 MHz. Idk but at least the installer is opening now.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to install Oracle JDeveloper 12c on `Apple M1 Pro` and the steps I followed are:

1. Download Generic Installer from https://www.oracle.com/tools/downloads/jdeveloper-12c-downloads.html#
2. Rename the `V998598-01.jar` file to `V998597-012.jar`
3. From download location, run the following command (with `JAVA_HOME` pointing to java 8 version)
   `java -jar V998597-01.jar -ignoreSysPrereqs`
4. The installation wizard will come up and you can set up as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You can install Oracle JDeveloper 12c on Mac with and without Apple Silicon. The type of Mac actually shouldn't make much of a difference I have found.